# How to sort songs from raw folder in my own order using arraylist

Tags: android

I am new to android development and I would like to sorts the songs in my own order which are in raw folder.I am using array list.Thanks you.

Comment: Look for comparator in java

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private List<File> getFilesList(File dir, String fileExt) {
    ArrayList<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            fileList.addAll(getListFiles(file));
        } else {
            if(file.getName().endsWith(fileExt)){
                fileList.add(file);
            }
        }
    }
    return fileList;
}

// get files list   
List<File> files = getFilesList(new File("your folder path", ".mp3")); 

// sort files in list based on filename
Collections.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(File file1, File file2)
    {
        return  file1.getName().compareTo(file2.getName());
    }
});
```

Comment: I am able to get alphabetical order since songs are in raw folder.But my question is how to sort the songs in my own order.Thanks for the help